# How to block user by navigating user in one screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, multithreading, closures

So here is the need I already have functions to check if user is logged in.

So my need is to have an overlay that will popup if user is already logged in and will have a button that will navigate to particular screen which has some forms to fill.

User should be blocked if he is logged in and doesn't have those information from the form screen.

What is the best approach to call and use that overlay?

Comment: why dont you take user to that screen directly instead of popup touch button to show the form screen. i had a similiar case in app a year ago where form data was mandatory so is user is login but those data are missing goin directly to that screen.

Comment: how to do that? because there are many users who are already logged in without that data.

Comment: how do you check is user is logged or not with token or so

Comment: for that I have a function which check if user is logged and has a session. and that's a good question to check where they are using it. Will check and put my code to navigate to form screen there. I believe that will work.

Comment: ok i think would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you you dont post how to check if user is loged or not I show how do I do it. using a access token. So in appDelegate **application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool**

```
if token != nil {

        if requestManager.instance.user.birthDate != nil && !requestManager.instance.user.iscomplete(){
            print("GOING TO DATANC")
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarVC")
            self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }else{
            print("GOING TO REGISTER")
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "register")
            //loginRequest.instance.delegate = initialViewController as profileViewController
            self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        } 
    }
```

so what's done here is to check if user has birthdate and have all info. iscomplete is funcion in the model returning true in case all values are set. if is complete then no data is missing, in your case you should check if formdata is missing or not, TABBAR is a storyBoard idetntifier for a tabbar controller but you cand adjust to whatever viewcontroller your should set in aplication flow. and register is the storyBoard idetifier for the viewcontroller where the data is missing so in you case must be the identifier of the form viewcontroller

Comment: Do you know how to do this in objective c? as my app delegate is in objective c

Comment: i dont know Obj-c  but you can make a translation google in, beside in your question you tagged swift not objetive-c so i write a swift answer

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will try it.

Comment: you shoulb vote the answer if works for you so others could use it too

Comment: sure if it works I will mark it as answer but for now I'm just giving it as up vote.

Comment: ok, i recommend you to try this, this was works for, I don't see any of your code but the idea is the same no overlay just redirection to proper viewcontroller